# Contrapositive Help

Tags: logic

The statement is as follows:
For every ε > 0 there is a point (x, y) in the plane whose distance from the origin is between ε/2 and ε.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I do not understand how to write the contrapositive for the statement.

Comment: There is not a point (x,y) in the plane whose distance from the origin is between ε/2 and ε for every ε < 0

Comment: Hint: there are various forms of negation, but it's common to have "for every" be the opposite of "there exists" and vice versa.

Comment: You have to negate : $\forall \epsilon \exists P (\epsilon/2 < d(P,O) < \epsilon)$, taking into account that : $\lnot \forall \exists$ is equivalent to : $\exists \forall \lnot$.

Comment: It isn’t clear what you want: the only kind of statement that has a contrapositive is an implication $\varphi\to\psi$, and its contrapositive is $\neg\psi\to\neg\varphi$. The suggestions that you’ve been given are for forming the *negation* of a statement, not its *contrapositive*. If the given statement is interpreted as ‘If $\epsilon>0$, then there is a point $\langle x,y\rangle$ in the plane whose distance is between $\epsilon/2$ and $\epsilon$’ (which, however, is not quite what it actually says), then it has a contrapositive that starts ‘If there is no point $\langle x,y\rangle ...’.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive is:

> If there is no point (x,y) in the plane whose distance from the origin is between $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon/2$, then $\epsilon\lt0$.

I would have said $\epsilon\le0$, which would be contrapositive to your original statement, which has left the case $\epsilon=0$ undefined, but is still true.